# Stats Model contingency table, unable to reshape data and run test for nd array 2 x 2 x k

Tags: python, categorical-data, contingency-tables, statsmodels, numpy

Consider below list of 2×2 tables and CMH (Cochran–Mantel–Haenszel) test results. We are trying to determine if each specific centre was associated with the success of the treatment [Data from Agresti, Categorical Data Analysis, second edition]

[image]

```
tables= [
[[11, 10], [25, 27]],
 [[16, 22], [4, 10]],
 [[14, 7], [5, 12]],
 [[2, 1], [14, 16]],
 [[6, 0], [11, 12]],
 [[1, 0], [10, 10]],
 [[1, 1], [4, 8]],
 [[4, 6], [2, 1]]]

cmh = sm.stats.contingency_tables.StratifiedTable(tables = tables)
print(cmh.test_null_odds())
pvalue ~ 0.012
statistic ~ 6.38
```

The tables parameters in [StratifiedTable](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.stats.contingency_tables.StratifiedTable.html) can also take a numpy array shape 2 × 2 × k, where k is a slice return each of the contingency tables.

**Q** → I've been unable to wrap my head around the array reshaping, this based on the above 8 × 2 × 2 shape the list of lists can more intuitively offer (at least for me).
Any thoughts on how to rerun this same test with a ndarray?

UPDATE: I've tried to reshape my tables var in numpy to a ndarray 2 × 2 × k, with a transpose. The below `TypeError` is raised when running the same test with

> `TypeError: No loop matching the specified signature and casting was found for ufunc true_divide`

*Note*: in R the following matrix would return the desired output

```
data = array (c(11, 10, 25, 27, 16, 22, 4, 10,
     14, 7, 5, 12, 2, 1, 14, 16,
      6, 0, 11, 12, 1, 0, 10, 10,
      1, 1, 4, 8, 4, 6, 2, 1), 
      c(2,2,8))
mantelhaen.test(data, correct=F)
```

Answer (score 0):

I missed/ not accounted for a dtype convertion when reshapping.

Your example worked for me with the transpose, .T. It looks like you have a separate problem with the dtype. Use float: `tables = np.asarray(tables).T.astype(float)` This was recently fixed github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/pull/7279